# Size of pointer of integer type vs Size of int*

Tags: c, pointers

I started reading Pointers and while tinkering with them. I stumbled upon this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int *p,a;
    a=sizeof(*p);
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

It outputs : 4

Then in the place of `sizeof(*p)` I replaced it with `sizeof(int*)`  Now it outputs 8 .

P is a pointer of integer type and int* is also the same thing ( Is my assumption correct? ). Then why it is printing two different values. I am doing this on a 64bit gcc compiler.

Comment: `sizeof(*p)` gives you the size of the type pointed to by `p` i.e. `sizeof(int)`.  Use `sizeof(p)` if you want to determine the size of an integer pointer

Comment: Repeat your experiment with `char *p`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Every beginner always gets confused with pointer declaration versus de-referencing the pointer, because the syntax looks the same.

- `int *p;` means "declare a pointer to int". You can also write it as `int* p;` (identical meaning, personal preference).
- `*p`, when used anywhere else but in the declaration, means "take the contents of what p points at".

Thus `sizeof(*p)` means "give me the size of the contents that p points at", but `sizeof(int*)` means "give me the size of the pointer type itself". On your machine, `int` is apparently 4 bytes but pointers are 8 bytes (typical 64 bit machine).

Answer (score 10):

`*p` and `int*` are not the same things! First one is a dereferenced pointer (i.e. `int` which is 4 bytes wide) and the second one is a pointer (8 bytes wide in your case since it's a 64 bit machine).

Comment: But here P is a pointer of  type integer and size of integer on my computer is 4 bytes. Then why P has 8 bytes?

Comment: There is no `P` anywhere it's `p`. And the `sizeof(p)` would be `8` but `sizeof(*p)` is for because it's the same as `sizeof(int)` not `sizeof(int *)`.

Comment: You need to bear in mind that `p` and `*p` are two different things. The first one is equivalent to `int*` and the second one to `int`. In other words, the first one is a pointer and the second one is an integer. A pointer has a fixed size regardless of the thing that it points to. So the size of a pointer on your machine will always be 8. It doesn't matter what it points to.

Comment: To add to the confusion: "*A pointer has a fixed size regardless of the thing that it points to.*" this is not necessary the case for any implementation of C.

Comment: @alk You are right. My comment is a generalization which works in most cases, but strictly speaking is not correct. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Surya: And, in reference to **here P is a pointer of type integer and size of integer on my computer is 4 bytes. Then why P has 8 bytes?**, size of all variables remain same in 32-bit and 64-bit system (except for the pointers). The size of a pointer will change to 8 bytes on 64-bit system since it holds an address, which is 64-bit long in 64-bit systems. Every pointer is  of 8 Bytes on a 64-bit system.