# How to use `sizeof` operator inside the condition of for-loop properly?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, for-loop, sizeof

Do the conditions of the for-loop always need constant? 
How can I put `sizeof` function there to run an output showing all the elements of an array?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void array_output(int a[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(a)) / (sizeof(a[0])); i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 22, 53, 13, 65, 80, 31, 46 };
    array_output(a);
    return 0;
}
```

- **`i<(sizeof(a)`** output shows first **`4` elements**
- **`i<(sizeof(a))/(sizeof(a[0]))`** output shows only the **first element**
- instead of `sizeof` when **`7`** is directly used as a condition, it gives
  the right output, showing **all the elements**.

Comment: Please post code that [**actually reproduces the problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Not some code you *assumed* would reproduce the problem. The second option works properly [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4c75852790b64ba).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When a function has a specific-size array parameter, why is it replaced with a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/when-a-function-has-a-specific-size-array-parameter-why-is-it-replaced-with-a-p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the actual array in the `sizeof` operator you will get the size of the array in bytes, meaning you can calculate the number of elements like you expected it using `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array_type)`.

```
int x[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};    
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(x) / sizeof(int); i++)
    sum += x[i];

// sum == 6
```

However if you pass the array as a function parameter you will encounter pointer decay. This means that the array size information is lost and you get the pointer size instead, which is the behavior that you described.

```
int sum(int arr[])  // arr decays to int*
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int); i++)
        sum += arr[i];

    return sum;
}

int main() 
{   
    int x[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};    
    return sum(x);  // will return 1 or 2, depending on architecture
}
```

You can still get the array size in the function if you use a template function for it.

```
#include <cstddef>

template <std::size_t N>
int sum(int (&arr)[N])
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        sum += arr[i];

    return sum;
}

int main() 
{   
    int x[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};    
    return sum(x);  // will return 6
}
```

Comment: @JeJo That statement was written after I posted this answer. And tbh I don't know what OP's trying to say with that sentence.

Comment: Well OP can also do `sizeof(arr)` in my last example instead of `N`. Doesn't make any difference.

Comment: true... But in your answer `N` makes more sense. What I meant is, you could have mentioned it in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>**†**</sup>(*This answer is for [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) users...*)

where no need of using `sizeof` operator at all.
Use instead **[`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size)** function which will get you the size of the given container or array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>  // std::size
#include <cstddef>   // std::size_t

int main()
{
    int a[]{ 22,53,13,65,80,31,46 };
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < std::size(a); i++)
    {
        std::cout << a[i] << `\n`;
    }
}
```

---

### <sup>**†**</sup> Update

The OP has edited the question after posting this answer,
where the `std::size` can not be applied.

When the array `a` passed to `void array_output(int a[])`, it deduced to `void array_output(int* a)`
instead if of the its actual type `int a[7]`.

- **`i<(sizeof(a)` output shows first `4` elements**

  Here, you are doing `size of(int*)` (*pointer to int*), depending up
  *[on the    architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436432/size-of-pointer-of-integer-type-vs-size-of-int)*
  it could be efferent. In your case it is `32` bit machine which is why you got `sizeof(a) = 4`.
- **`i < sizeof(a)/ sizeof(a[0])` output shows only the first element**

  Dividing `sizeof(a)`(*which is `sizeof(int*`) equal to `4` bytes in
  your machine*) by `sizeof(a[0])`(*which is `sizeof(int)`, also `4` bytes*), is nothing but one and loops only once.

The *[@Timo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56127626/how-to-put-sizeof-function-inside-the-conditions-of-for-loop-properly/56127949#56127949)*'s
answer, provide a templated function where size will be a non-type template parameter, which can be accessed directly, without going for `sizeof`.

---

> How can I put `sizeof` in function and run an output showing all the
>   elements of an array?

This is possible **only** when passing the array `a` of actual type as it is. 
For that, let the array to deduce to its `int [7]`, by **forwarding it perfectly**.

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename Type>
void array_output(Type&& a) // deduced to `int a[7]`
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++) { // or std::size(a)
        std::cout << a[i] << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 22, 53, 13, 65, 80, 31, 46 };
    array_output(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Though if `sizeof` didn't work, it means that in OP's actual code they use a pointer rather than an arrya, so `std::size` won't work as well.

Comment: OP updated the code and indeed `std::size` of will "work" just as `sizeof` does (they both dont)

Answer (score 1):

You can use vector for this.

```
vector<int> nums{1,2,3,4};
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
  cout<<nums[i]<<endl;
```

If you insist on using int a[], you should be aware of the size before traversing it.
By the way, on GCC

```
sizeof(nums) = sizeof(int) * total number of element
```

it's not the total number of element.

Comment: 1) Don't use `int` for `i`: `size()` returns `std::size_t` and then you're comparing a signed type `int` to an unsigned one `std::size_t` that is a bad thing to do; 2) in C++11 you can do this: `for (auto& x : nums) std::cout << x << std::endl;`.

Comment: @Evg  you are right